# Firebase LatLng is missing a constructor with no arguments

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am storing coordinates in a realtime database and I am getting an error message when trying to retrieve data. The error message is

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng is missing a constructor with no arguments

...

> at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)

Here is the code

Main.java

```
protected void onStart() {
        apiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();

        DatabaseReference test = database.getReference("jsierra");

        test.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Child Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                givenData = dataSnapshot.getValue(data.class); <-- Error
            }
}
```

data.java

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
public class data {
    private LatLng coordinates;

    public data() {
        coordinates = null;
    }

    public data(LatLng coordinates)
    {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public void setLatLng(LatLng coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    LatLng getLatLng () {
        return coordinates;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create your own `LatLng` model class instead of using the one from Google Maps library because it lacks a public constructor in the implementation.

```
public class LatLng {
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    public LatLng() {}

    ... public getter ...
}
```

**EDIT:** how to convert this `LatLng` to `com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng`

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng mapsLatLng = 
    new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(latLng.getLatitude(),
                                                 latLng.getLongitude());
```

Comment: I have a bit of an issue with that because I am using Google Maps circle and marker. So when I get rid of the Google Maps LatLng and create my own I get error message on marker and circle since they request Google Maps LatLng.

Comment: @JuanSierra yeah, you can't directly use other LatLng to Google Maps methods. That's why you need to convert it back to Google Maps' LatLng. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: @Wilik where does the conversion go??

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when I tried to pass Timestamp to database. While getter worked and my data were set to realtime database correctly with push,  reading the data using the DataSnapshot from ChildEventListener crashed my app with the error because also the Timestamp class has no public cunstructor with no arguement.
So I created my own class Timestamp that extended the original java Timestamp class, added the missing public constructor with no arguement.

```
public class Timestamp extends java.sql.Timestamp {

public Timestamp(long time) {
    super(time);
}

public Timestamp(){
    super(System.currentTimeMillis());

}
```

I had to then include also the needed setters (as read from warnings when using my new class)