# datasnapshot.getvalue() does not work and crashes app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from firebase real-time database in the form of `BusInformation.class`. But my app crashes while setting the class type of snapshot at this point: `ds.getValue(BusInformation.class);`

I am getting the following error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.example.muzammil.bustracking.app_classes.BusInformation does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
```

Following is code for BuInformation.java class:

```
public class BusInformation {
    private String id, username,phone;
    private LatLng position;
    private String destination;

    public BusInformation(String id, String username, String phone,  String destination,LatLng position) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.position = position;
        this.destination = destination;
    }
}
```

In Firebase database the data exist exactly in this form.

The code for getting data from firebase:

```
 public void getUpdatesFromFirebase(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            if(ds.exists()) {
                busInfo = ds.getValue(BusInformation.class);  //App crashes at this point

            }

        }
    }
```

Any body please tell me what is wrong with the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BusInformation does not define a no-argument constructor.`

Manually add a no-arg constructor to it: `public BusInformation(){}`

Your class should look like this:

```
public class BusInformation {
    private String id, username,phone;
    private LatLng position;
    private String destination;

    //no-argument constructor
    public BusInformation(){}

    public BusInformation(String id, String username, String phone,  String destination,LatLng position) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.position = position;
        this.destination = destination;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for response. The exception now changed to this: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.

Comment: That is another problem. You should accept an answer if it answered your question. Regarding the following problem check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41192129/7972851) answer.